Error dependencias SAML2 proyecto Spring
Sucede que coloco las dependencias para realizar la parte de seguridad SAML2 pero al momento descargarlas me lanza el siguiente error:
Could not transfer artifact org.opensaml:opensaml-core:pom:4.3.2 from/to shibboleth_repository (https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tengo estas dependencias:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

Intente agregar este repositorio:
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>shibboleth_repository</id>
        <name>Shibboleth Maven Repository</name>
        <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

Pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error
Gracias por sus comentarios.

intenta correrlo así: mvn clean package -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true y nos cuentas si te funciona

@RuslanLópez hola amigo, buen día, me estaba funcionando pero al último me aparecio este error:
cannot access org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
bad class file: C:\Users.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.3.0\spring-boot-3.3.0.jar(org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.class)
class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

eso ya es por tu versión de Java, revisa en el sitio si ya existe una pregunta par ese problema
